# How can I query specific columns in a VBA macro used to transfer data across workbooks?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using a Excel macro to transfer data between works with ADO by following these guidelines. Currently, I've set up the code to search for a keyword in column A of the source file. Once it finds the keyword, it will copy data from that entire row. However, I only need data from columns G-I, and cannot find the information to condense the data selection.

```
Public Sub MoveData()


    'defines the project name as a variable
    Dim fileName As String
        fileName = Worksheets("Cover").Range("B5").Value

    'defines the path
    Dim path As String
        path = "C:\Users\(user)\Documents\(folder)\" & fileName & ".csv"

    'defines the two workbooks that the data will move between
    Dim currentWB As Workbook
    Set currentWB = ThisWorkbook

    Dim openWB As Workbook
    Set openWB = Workbooks.Open(path)

    Dim openWs As Worksheet
    Set openWs = openWB.Sheets(fileName)

    'connects using ADODB to transfer the data
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection                      
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & path & ";" & _
    "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;"
        .Open
    End With

    'selects the first column to be read and sorted
    Dim subCell As Range
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range("A1:A500")


    Dim cmdOpen As Boolean
    cmdOpen = False


    For Each subCell In myRange
        'searches for the column markups
        If subCell Like "*COLUMN*" Then


            strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" & fileName & "$] Where Subject = '" & subCell.Value & "'"

            Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
            With cmd
                .ActiveConnection = cn
                .CommandText = strQuery
            End With


            Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
            With rst
            If cmdOpen = False Then
                .Open cmd
                cmdOpen = True
            End If
            End With

            currentWB.Worksheets("Cols").Range("B7:D7").CopyFromRecordset rst

        End If
    Next subCell
    openWB.Close


End Sub
```

This  `strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" & fileName & "$] Where Subject = '" & subCell.Value & "'"` is the line I am referring to. It selects the row of data where the keyword is found. I want to limit this selection to columns G-I. Any advice on how I could accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the column headers? If so, specify them rather than `*`

Comment: Use `Select [Column 1], [Column 2] FROM [" & fileName & "$] Where Subject = '" & subCell.Value & "'"` instead of `*`( [Column 1], [Column 2] are the column headers)